# Can we interchange Key and Value in AvroParquetInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro, parquet

We are introducing Parquet data format instead of Avro in our MR jobs.

We have used AvroParquetInputFormat which gives LongWritable as key and GenericRecord as value. But I want key as GenericRecord and value can be anything (doesn't matter).

Comment: Why does it matter which way round they are? Practically, there isn't much difference.

Comment: Actually there are hundreds of existing MR jobs, where key is the genericRecord in the mapper and values are NullWritable.
Therefore, If we get the key value pair in similar way, we do not need to change the mapper and reducer code.

Comment: @BinaryNerd Please see the above comment

Comment: The easiest and cleanest option is probably to extend `AvroParquetInputFormat` so that the key and value are switched, you would then change everything to use this custom input format.